# Django Error: Reverse for 'blog_detail_url' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<id>\\d+)$']

Tags: python, django

On my blog, I am trying to create a URL pager system where I can link to the previous and next post by the ID of the Post model. Right now, every time I try to go to a blog web page I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /blog/2
Reverse for 'blog_detail_url' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<id>\\d+)$']
```

**views.py:**

```
def blog_detail(request, id):
    # post request from the url
    return render(request, "BlogHome/pages/post.html")
    post = Post.objects.get(id)

    # Next Post
    try:
        Next_Post_id = (post.id + 1)
        Next_Post = Post.objects.get(id=Next_Post_id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        Next_Post = None

    # Previous Post
    try:
        Previous_Post_id = (post.id - 1)
        Previous_Post = Post.objects.get(id=Previous_Post_id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        Previous_Post = None

    context = {'post': post, 'Next_Post': Next_Post, 'Previous_Post': Previous_Post}
    return render(request, "BlogHome/pages/post.html", context)
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.blog_list),
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)$', views.blog_detail, name='blog_detail_url'),
]
```

**post.html:**

```
{% extends "BlogHome/includes/WELL.html" %}

{% block content %}
<script>
document.title = "Pike Dzurny | {{post.title}}"
</script>

<div class="container-fluid text-center">

    <center>

        <div class="well" id="WellPost">

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <h2 align="center" id="TitleText">{{post.title}}</h2>
                <h3 align="center" id="BodyText">{{ post.date|date:"m-d"}}</h3>
                <h3 align="left">{{ post.body|safe }}</h3>

                {% if Next_Post is defined and Previous_Post is defined %}
                <ul class="pager">
                    <li class="previous"><a href="{% url 'blog:blog_detail_url' Post.id %}"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Older</a></li>
                    <li class="next "><a href="{% url 'blog:blog_detail_url' Next_Post.id %}">Newer <span
                            aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a></li>
                    <h1>1</h1>
                </ul>

                {% elif Next_Post is defined %}
                <ul class="pager">
                    <li class="previous disabled"><a href=""><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Older</a></li>
                    <li class="next"><a href="{% url 'blog:blog_detail_url' Next_Post.id %}">Newer <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <h1>2</h1>

                {% elif Previous_Post is defined %}
                <ul class="pager">
                    <li class="previous"><a href="{% url 'blog:blog_detail_url' Post.id %}"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span>
                        Older</a></li>
                    <li class="next disabled"><a href="">Newer <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <h1>3</h1>

                {% else %}
                <ul class="pager">
                    <li class="previous disabled"><a href="{% url 'blog:blog_detail_url' Post.id %}"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Older</a></li>
                    <li class="next disabled"><a href="{% url 'blog:blog_detail_url' Next_Post.id %}">Newer <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <h1>4</h1>
                {% endif %}


            </div>
    </center>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

The error is happening at line 22 in post.html (`<li class="previous"><a href="{% url 'blog:blog_detail_url' Post.id %}"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Older</a></li>`). I'm guessing, I imporperly set up the jinja2 href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your links from

```
"{% url 'blog:blog_detail_url' Next_Post.id %}"
```

to

```
"{% url 'blog:blog_detail_url' id=Next_Post.id %}"
```

Notice the `id=`. Your url pattern specifies `id` as a url kwarg.

Also, as a rule of thumb, you should not name your variables with upper-case letters. In Python, it's standard to use lower-case variable names, and then have upper case names for classes. When this is done consistently, it helps make your code more readable.

**EDIT**

This also seems a little fishy to me: `{% if Next_Post is defined and Previous_Post is defined %}` what is `defined` ? I don't see it in the context or anywhere else. I would do this:

```
{% if next_post %}
    {# ... #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The error is now `Reverse for 'blog_detail_url' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<id>\\d+)$']
`

Comment: @PikeD. You will want to pass the `id` not the object, so stick `next_post_id` into your context and use that.

Comment: Ah, I did not notice that. Thank you!

Comment: @PikeD. it's also possible that in your view when you are attempting to get the next post id that it's throwing an exception and getting set to None

Comment: [This section from the Jinja2 documentation shows what `defined` is](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#defined)

Comment: Oh - didn't realize it was jinja2

Comment: Though, you are probably right. Reading over the documentation it tests only to see if it's defined, not set to `None`.